# Placing a checkbox submission into html eblast

Tags: html, email, html-email, html-helper, mailchimp

I am trying to send an eBlast from mailchimp with a form embedded with checkboxes that when the button is pressed it sends a reply with whatever box they have chosen. Then their responses would be put into a google excel sheet so we know who is RSVPing. Is there a way to do this? Maybe there is an easier way and Im going about it wrong. Would love your guys help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Forms in emails are only supported by a handful of email clients. An easier option/method would be to take them to a landing when a user clicks on yes, no or rsvp button. That page can give the right confirmation measage depending on what option a user has chosen.